# How do I fix red and green blocks with CSS ？

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

everyone
Would like to ask at present I am making a version when the web page to slide up the red and green block to be fixed, only the yellow block can slide!
The current treatment on the green side is using

```
 position:sticky;
 right:0px;
 top:100px;
```

The grammar keeps him fixed there, but there's a problem because if you don't give height it looks like it's position:sticky; I want his height to be customizable, so I give him a height of 200px; As a result, when the content is too much or in RWD mode, it goes out of the green zone.

Is there a better way to fix the red and green blocks?

Here's what I'm trying to do so far.
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/wvgbbye?editors=1100

Comment: Can you set ```align-items: flex-start;``` to your container and remove the fixed height for the green box.

Comment: " I want his height to be customizable" it is not clear what you're referring to by "him", "his" etc. Please use `red`, `green`, `yellow` instead

Comment: _“Here's what I'm trying to do so far”_ - please go read [ask] and [mre]. The minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem, belong as directly into your question, not just dumped onto an external platform.

Answer (score 1):

Add `align-items: flex-start;` to your `.container` class and remove any height value from the `aside`.

```css
.wrap{
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.header{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f75454;
  box-shadow:0px 1px 30px #212529;
  z-index: 1;
  
}

.header .list{
  display: flex;
  padding:20px;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  padding:30px;
  padding-top: 100px;
  background-color: #5c5c5c;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.main{
  flex:2;
  padding:20px;
  height: 1600px;
  margin:0px 20px;
  background-color: #f9cf5a;
}

.aside{
  position:sticky;
  right:0px;
  top:100px;
  padding:20px;
  flex:1;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1ba784;
  color:#eef7f2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="header">
    <ul class="list">
      <li>測試</li>
      <li>測試</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum expedita pariatur facere repellat nobis sed modi, porro, at numquam accusantium aut consequuntur delectus ducimus atque officia dolores! Dolore quas delectus fuga accusantium quia atque esse, non, aut quae optio officia odit natus accusamus, libero iure nam? Accusantium veritatis ad repellat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="aside">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex assumenda officiis sunt laboriosam impedit fuga tenetur pariatur distinctio ipsum suscipit.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex assumenda officiis sunt laboriosam impedit fuga tenetur pariatur distinctio ipsum suscipit.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ex assumenda officiis sunt laboriosam impedit fuga tenetur pariatur distinctio ipsum suscipit.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for your help!

However, I further tried that when the green block had more content and text, it would still outnumber the red block!

Do you know how to solve it? Thank you.

My lab website
https://codepen.io/hong-wei/pen/QWdXwJK

Comment: What do you mean outnumber? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: If you mean, that it scrolls over the red bar instead over under, simply add some ```z-index```.